# How to debug a project that references DLLs in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, c#, dll, visual-studio-2017

I am running a project in VS17. I have both managed and unmanaged code. My c# code references and calls a function from a DLL written in c++. I would like to be able to use the debugger to step through the DLL/c++ code as I debug the c# application.  I have tried turning on native code debugging but have had difficulties making anything function.

Comment: Do you have the debug symbols for the reference file in question?  The simplest way to do this is to attach the project for the reference file to the solution for the application so both are compiled and can be debugged.

Comment: I do have the pdb for the dll I am calling. How would I attach the project for the reference file?

Comment: The best way is for the `.pdb` file to reside in the same folder as the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

> My c# code references and calls a function from a DLL written in c++. I would like to be able to use the debugger to step through the DLL/c++ code as I debug the c# application.

You have to specify the location of the debugging symbol for the reference file.

> To specify symbol locations and loading options:
>
> 1. In Visual Studio, open Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Under Symbol file (.pdb) locations add the location of the debugging `.pdb` file for the reference file in question.
>
> Note: Only the specified folder is searched. You must add entries for any subfolders that you want to search.
>
> By default, if you have built a DLL or an .exe file on your computer, the linker places the full path and filename of the associated .pdb file in the DLL or .exe file. The debugger checks to see if the symbol file exists in that location.

Source: [Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger (C#, C++, Visual Basic, F#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017)

Comment: The reference link also includes the instructions for all support versions of Visual Studio.  Worth pointing out that Visual Studio 2019 had additional C++ (manged and unmanaged) debugging capabilities that do not exist in Visual Studio 2017.